# Discover a Character level by his accumulated experience

Tags: sequences-and-series

Because of storage limitations, the game can only store the Character's total experience, and anytime the Character's Level is needed, i have to calculate from the given experience.

characterLevel(amount of experience) { calculates and returns level; }

I managed to do it, using a loop from level 1 to MaxLevel, and adding the accumulated experience, accounting by the experience per level change, but it's terrible to do up to 100 loops everytime, i just couldn't find any other solution.

This is the Experience and Level progression:

| Character's Level | Experience gained during Level | Experience needed for next Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 30 |
| 2 | 10 | 60 |
| 3 | 20 | 120 |
| 4 | 20 | 180 |
| 5 | 30 | 270 |
| 6 | 30 | 360 |
| 7 | 40 | 480 |
| 8 | 40 | 600 |
| 9 | 50 | 750 |
| 10 | 50 | 900 |

A character in level 1, gains 10 exp per battle, until he accumulates 30 exp, then he's lvl 2; A character in level 2, gains 10 exp per battle, until he accumulates 60 exp, then he's lvl 3; A character in level 3, gains 20 exp per battle, until he accumulates 120 exp, then he's lvl 4;

The (exp per battle) increases by 10 every 2 levels. The (exp needed for next level) is the previous level + 3 times the current (exp per battle).

Given only the accumulated experience, let's say 720, is there an elegant way of finding out wich level is the character?

Thank you very much! Sorry if the question isn't very clear, english isn't my first language.

Comment: We see a sequence where one needs $+30, +60,+60,+90+90,+120,+120,+150,+150$.  Notice the pattern

Comment: Why don't you just take the table you have already created, and run a lookup on it?

Comment: @DavidP, thank you, i see the pattern now, but from 720 for example, at what number do i start dividing? Do i use modulo?

Comment: @DougM unfortunately i can't store the values of the table, any other sugestion? Thank you!